# MVC radio buttons disabled readonly when not authenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, true)
@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, "Accepted")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, false)
@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, "Rejected")
```

What I'm wanting is for some way to make these disabled or readonly when the user isn't Authenticated.

ie. Enabled when:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Would you put them on some sort of panel? Not sure for MVC?

Would you set there enabledability individually for each line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm wanting is for some way to make these disabled or readonly
>   when the user isn't Authenticated.

A more than excellent candidate for a custom helper:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class RadioExtensions // LOL for this name
{ 
    // TODO: Pick a better name here than MyRadioButtonFor
    public static IHtmlString MyRadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex,
        object value
    )
    {
        var isAuthenticated = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            return html.RadioButtonFor(ex, value);
        }
        // Remark: adapt with readonly if necessary,
        // note that there is a crucial difference between a readonly and disabled
        // element in HTML. Up to you to pick the desired behavior
        return html.RadioButtonFor(ex, value, new { @disabled = "disabled" });
    }
}
```

and in your view simply consume the fruits of your labour:

```
@Html.MyRadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, true)
@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, "Accepted")
@Html.MyRadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, false)
@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, "Rejected")
```